# Can't set up ssh login without typing password

Tags: ssh

I set up automatically ssh login without typing password to a server by:

```
cd ~/.ssh

ssh-keygen

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub tim@server1
```

It works on the server.

Later I did the same on a different server.

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub tim@server2
```

Immediately I `ssh tim@server2`, but it still requires my password. Did I do something incorrectly? What are some possible reasons that I didn't set up successfully on the second server? (note that the second server runs kerberos and Andrew file system)

```
$ ssh -v tim@server2
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server2 [...] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xxx
debug1: Host 'server2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts:70
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

---

I tried Anthon's method of using Diffie-Hellman keys, but it still asks me for my password.

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub tim@server2
$ ssh -v tim@server2
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server2 [...] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ...
debug1: Host 'server2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts:70
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

Comment: Is your home directory mounted after you login?

Comment: After each login in the past, my home was always mounted.

Comment: Yes, once you login, you get your home directory - but what about before the login is complete? (Consider encrypted home directories, or a network home directory, etc.)

Comment: I heard `server2` uses Andrew file system. Does that mean my home is not mounted before login is complete? How can I find it out for your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how the Andrew filesystem works, but if you have another login at the same server, use it and see if you can see the contents of `tim`'s home directory.

Comment: no user can see content of another user's home directory.

Comment: Who can disable GSS on server2? I am not a admin

Answer (score 12):

You mention that the second server is using the Andrew File System (AFS).

I haven't worked with that, but from what I understand it, AFS is a Kerberos-secured filesystem which requires a kerberos ticket in order to work. That means you need to be logged to your site's Kerberos realm in order to be able to access your home directory.

If you log on with password, `server2` is likely set up so that it logs you on to your Kerberos realm through PAM. If you're using SSH keys, however, then `server2` won't get the information it requires to do that, and you won't be able to access your home directory.

Luckily, from the `ssh -v` output in your question, we can infer that your server has `GSSAPI` authentication enabled. This should allow you to perform a passwordless logon, provided you have a valid kerberos ticket for your realm. Do the following:

- Log on to `server2`, and run the `klist` program. This will return something along the following lines:

  ```
  Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_2000
  Default principal: wouter@EXAMPLE.ORG

  Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
  28-05-15 15:01:31  29-05-15 01:01:31  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ORG@EXAMPLE.ORG
      renew until 29-05-15 15:01:28
  28-05-15 15:02:04  29-05-15 01:01:31  IMAP/example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
      renew until 29-05-15 15:01:28
  ```

  look for the line which starts with `Default principal:`. It tells you what your kerberos principal is (in the above example, it's `wouter@EXAMPLE.ORG`). Write this down. Note that it's not an email address, and that it is case-sensitive; i.e., the principal ends with `EXAMPLE.ORG`, not `example.org`.
- On your client machine, run `kinit` with the name of your principal (i.e., in the above example, that would be `kinit wouter@EXAMPLE.ORG`). If all goes well, when you run `klist` again now, you will see that you have a ticket cache on your local machine.
- If you now run `ssh -K server2`, you should be able to log on, and the system should not ask for a password.

Please note that due to how Kerberos works, a ticket cache has a limited validity. It is not possible to ask for a ticket cache with validity longer than what the realm administrator configured (which is usually something like 10 hours or so). Once your ticket has expired, you will need to run `kinit` again, and enter your password once more.

Comment: thanks. "On your client machine, run kinit", do you mean I have to install Kerberos on my local Ubuntu?

Comment: Part of the kerberos tools, yes. You'll find the required tools in the `krb5-user` package.

Comment: Should I use rsa or dsa when creating the public keys and copying them to the server? (I followed Anthon's suggestion to use dsa right now)

Comment: Due to AFS on the server, you can't use SSH public keys, you need to use kerberos instead. So it doesn't matter ;-)

Comment: Are GSSAPI, dsa, and rsa all authentication methods?

Comment: No. GSSAPI is, and so is SSH key exchange. RSA and DSA are public-key encryption algorithms that can be used for various things, including Kerberos and SSH keys.

Answer (score 5):

You should try to connect to server2 with:

```
ssh -v tim@server2
```

and compare that with the same, connecting to `server1` this will tell you exactly where the two servers differ.

Most likely there is a difference in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on both machines. where `server2` or your `~/.ssh` has accessibility problems (not restricted enough).

From the `-v` output you can see that you offer an RSA private key to verify against (in `/home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa`), but it looks like `server2` only supports Diffie-Hellman (and tries  `/home/tim/.ssh/id_dsa` which is probably not even there).

Comment: thanks, I updated with the output of running your command. Not sure what it means

Comment: @Tim  updated my answer, you should check with the server2 administrator why it doesn't seem to support RSA private/public keys.

Comment: Besides asking the admin (which I think is impossible to make any change based on my experiences), Is there some way to work with what the server expects?

Comment: @Tim, first make sure that `~/.ssh` on the server indeed has your authorized keys installed ( `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`). Then what you could try to do is have `ssh-keygen` generate a diffie-hellman key pair using `ssh-keygen -t dsa` and copy that over.

Comment: (1) There is a file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. Does that mean that it has the authorized keys installed? (2) how shall I copy the generated diffie-hellman key pair to the server? by `scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub tim@server2:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? will that overwrite `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server?

Comment: @tim it most likely has your RSA public key. You can just use the same `ssh-copy-id` but specify the `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` file. It should just add the extra key to the `authorized_keys` file

Comment: it still asks me for my password. see my update

Comment: If the dsa key is appended to `authorized_keys` file after the previous key, how can it tell when  which key in the file is used?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following entry in the client machine from which you are trying to ssh.

config file: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

After that you will able to ssh to the machine.

If you don't have edit permissions for that file, you can also add

```
Host *
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

to `~/.ssh/config` (create this file if it does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar issue and solved it.

When I continued and logged on using a password i still got further warnings

```
Remote: Ignored authorized keys: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/myusername/.ssh
```

Common error is forgetting to change to the correct permissions on both client and server

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_key
```

Anything to do with gssapi is a red-herring.

The root cause is an issue trying to connect using the publickey

publickey->gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic->password

your debug files looks different to mine, due to different version of ssh but looking at the line :-

```
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
```

I'd try checking your permissions on the folder and file first.